# Create video from one picture and one audio file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, youtube

I'm trying to create a video from one picture and one audio file. The video should be as long as the audio file, displaying the same picture the whole duration.

This command does not work correctly. The video is longer than the audio file:
`ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2/60 -i 22.jpg -i 22.mp3 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a copy -shortest -r 2 video-output.mkv`

And this command also does not work correctly. The video is cannot be converted for YouTube servers. (After video upload on YouTube I see error message, that video is no possible process):
`ffmpeg -r 1 -i 22.jpg -i 22.mp3 -c:a copy -r 1 -c:v libvpx-vp9 video-output2.mkv`

The audio and picture can be downloaded here:
https://mega.nz/folder/JuID2BiA#uZ4qVDe6yb0xjDjiXFlJvw

I prefer lossless audio without reencoding

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . Can you please provide more details on what you mean by "*video is cannot be converted for YouTube servers*"? How are you trying to "convert it" and what's the error?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. After video upload on YouTube I see error message, that video is no possible process, if I create video from this command:
`   ffmpeg -r 1 -i 22.jpg -i 22.mp3 -c:a copy -r 1 -c:v libvpx-vp9 video-output2.mkv`
On VLC player play this video correct. But for youtube servers it is problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (adapted from the [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Addingaudio)):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 22.jpg -i 22.mp3 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest video-output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. But this command create video with 30 per second framerate and it work too slow on my old computer with long videos. …. I found solution. Use first command and then shorten video with LossLessCut app https://www.mifi.no/losslesscut/ . It work on my Ubuntu Linux correct. Notify me, if you have better solution via FFMPEG command only

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Using [this reference](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/YouTube):

> Because YouTube, Vimeo, and other similar sites will re-encode
> anything you give it the best practice is to provide the highest
> quality video that is practical for you to upload. Uploading the
> original content is the first recommendation, but this is not always a
> choice due to the file size or format, so re-encoding may be required.
> This guide will show you how to create a high quality video using
> ffmpeg.

Based on the example under "Create a video with a still image (input.png) and an audio file (audio.m4a):" and to make the output lossless, I used this command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i 22.jpg -i 22.mp3 -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 -preset medium -qp 0 -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -movflags faststart output.mkv
```

Available on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUw-BZRDF5M

To verify the output audio is lossless, I used several tools and compare results from Spek for;

1. Original audio file (22.mp3)
2. Audio extracted from output.mkv (output.mp3)

[image: Comparison using Spek]

After some checking and verification of the uploaded videos, it seems Youtube has a cutoff frequency for the audio between 15-18KHz.  See [here](https://forums.stevehoffman.tv/threads/how-do-you-sidestep-the-15-khz-cap-on-youtube-video-posts.650452/) for more information, but it doesn't seem like there is a way around that.

Also, Youtube has recommended encoding parameters listed [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6039860?hl=en#zippy=%2Cvideo-option-h-codec%2Cvideo-option-mpeg--transport-stream).

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. But I prefer lossless audio without quality loss. Video created by lossless audio is very fast created on my very old computer. …. I found solution. Use first command and then shorten video with LossLessCut app https://www.mifi.no/losslesscut/ . It work on my Ubuntu Linux correct. Notify me, if you have better solution via FFMPEG command only

Comment: I have modified the answer to make it lossless using only ffmpeg. To verify it is lossless, I compared the audio from the original and the generated output.mkv to ensure the output audio is lossless.